# How to call vuejs function from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

[image]

How to call order function from successCallback ? The code is vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier if the code you posted would be complete but my guess is:

Use arrow functions

```
var successCallback = payment_id => {
    // now "this" refers to this vue component instance so:
    this.order()
}
```

or store reference to `this` and use it like a variable

```
var that = this
var successCallback = function (payment_id) {
    // this is *this* function
    // "that" is a vue instance
    that.order()
}
```